# MySQL SEC_TO_TIME gives hh:mm:ss.000000

Tags: mysql

As said in the caption I am wondering why the `SEC_TO_TIME`-Function of MySQL gives me that Zeros at the end.

Refering to the docu (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) that shouldn't happen (I am using MySQL 5.0.11).

Any Idea why this Zeros appears and how to get rid of them? To much zeros for displaying miliseconds.

Sine the zeros doens't break MySQLs Date-funcions, it's more a *"I don't like that"*-Question rather than a real Problem (at least till now^^)

// EDIT: I just figured out that the zeros aren't coming from the SEC_TO_TIME but from the FROM_UNIXTIME()-Function. Thx to @Abhik Chakraborty to ask for the input!

// EDIT2: I used `FROM_UNIXTIME(last_try, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')` to get rid of the zeros. But When I do `TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_try, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))` the zeros are back. Why??

Seems like every function adds the zeros back. Using `SEC_TO_TIME` on a simple integer-value also gives zeros...

Here is the whole query iam using:

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC((TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`last_try`))))/1800)*1800)
FROM `last48h`
```

The query reads the timestamp, gets only the time, converts it to seconds, breaks the seconds into half-hours (/1800 gives 0 < x < 48) rounds down and converts back to time

Comment: what are your input values that you are converting ?

Comment: See second edit. I am reading a column type int which holds a timestamp (without fraction - only seconds). I convert that time back to seconds after manipulating it.

Comment: What client software are you using to give these commands? Can you show the exact line of SQL yielding the extra zeros?

Comment: I use the webinterface phpMyAdmin to run the SQL. I wil update the answer with the whole query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEC_TO_TIME produces a TIME data type for its result. You can format that as you wish with DATE_FORMAT.

If you actually need subsecond time resolution you'll need to move to version 5.6.4 or beyond.

When you directly SELECT any sort of TIME data type to display, you get a default TIME-to-string conversion operation.  The default TIME-to-string conversion in some generations of MySQL yields a string ending in `hh:mm:ss+zz00`. `+zz00` is a timezone indicator, and often displays as `+0000`. Any chance that's what you're seeing?

It doesn't make sense to try to handle a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` style number of seconds using `SEC_TO_TIME()`.  As of mid-2014 the current unix timestamp value is above 1.39 gigaseconds. TIME data types are used for stuff like elapsed times, and have a limit of just under 839 hours (3 megaseconds, precisely 3020399 seconds), and **silently truncate** their values.

For example, this is a good use of SEC_TO_TIME:

```
   SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(end_timestamp - start_timestamp) AS duration
```

**edit**
Strangely enough, this query

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC((TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))))/1800)*1800) AS a,
  FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC((TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))))/1800)*1800 AS b,
  TIME_TO_SEC((TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()))))/1800 AS c,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS d,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 1800) as e
```

doesn't show any of the `0000` stuff through the phpmyadmin instance I use.

By the way, most people who round time to the nearest interval (a half-hour in your case) prefer to use a modulo and a subtraction; it's less dependent on implicit numerical type conversion than your method.

```
 SELECT TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_try - last_try%1800))
```

does what the query in your question does.

Comment: See my second edit. Ty for poiting out the format-stuff.

Comment: And i was that proud about that query... As alwas there is just a simple solution... Thank you^^

Comment: @Fuzzyma, I have been there and done that myself :-) There is only one good way to learn. Keep on coding!

Comment: Its worth to mention that I still get the zeros even with your query. Well - Since I want the whole timestamp of this date - rounded to half-hour, I just glued the time and the date with `timestamp` and used this in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and that removed the zeros

Comment: Or i just do `last_try - last_try%1800` - was just to easy to see -.-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the 'SEC_TO_TIME' function.

I had overlooked the fact that I was storing timestamps as a VARCHAR.

I changed my datatypes from  VARCHAR to BIGINT and it is formatting the output values as expected (hh:mm:ss).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) with %k specifier it should help.